# Xamarin vs native cost/licence limitation

Tags: xamarin

I have been out of .NET and normal software development world for half year (new job needs me to use MS Dynamics) and now looking to learn Android (for hobby). I have options to either learn Xamarin or just go native. I'm not sure which one would be better in long term. I'm more comfortable in C# than Java, but that's only because I did 5 years in C# and stopped Java after university. Going back to Java should just be a minor problem.

My concern now is the cost/licence limitation on Xamarin.

1. Can I learn Xamarin for free? I'm guessing this is a yes ever since Microsoft bought them, right?
2. Is there any limits on the size of codes, whatever for Xamarin that will force me to buy the licence?

Short question is: Is Xamarin totally free - starting from learning-development-publishing?

Comment: StackOverflow is not generic discussion forum, question like this are Off-Topic here

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/

Comment: @Meier did not know that. Sorry, will not happen again

Comment: @Meier Rather than simply stating that SO isn't for generic software development questions like these, it may help if you point the OP to the correct stackexchange forum where such questions can be asked.

Answer (score 3):

Note: The only limitation is there are some *additional* tools that are only available to **Visual Studio `Enterprise` license** holders, other than that, have fun coding.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/xamarin-vs

> Now with Xamarin
>
> Deliver native Android, iOS, and Windows apps, with a single shared C# codebase

https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/

> Visual Studio now includes Xamarin
>   As of today, we are including Xamarin in Visual Studio at no extra cost.
>
> Xamarin will be in every edition of Visual Studio, including the widely-available Visual Studio Community Edition, which is free for individual developers, open source projects, academic research, education, and small professional teams. Develop and publish native apps for iOS and Android with C# or F# from directly within Visual Studio with no limits on app size.
>
> For developers on the Mac, Xamarin Studio is now available as a benefit of your Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise subscription. Developers can use the newly-created Xamarin Studio Community Edition for free.

Download: http://aka.ms/xam1

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about Xamarin for free with MVA courses, an edX course and Charles Petzold's book. Find these resources here:

[MVA, edX, book](https://mva.microsoft.com/colleges/xamarin)

[Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=xamarin#ch9Search)